# How to use matches from storage in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want `something.js` executed on the url user inputed in option page.

manifest.json:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.google.com/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "something.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

This way, it is hardcoded, I want to let user input the desired url in chrome extension option page, and the inputed url will be saved in storage as `matches_url` and when current page's url matches the url in `matches_url`, `something.js` should be injected.

How can I do that?

Comment: [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) in Chrome or [contentScripts.register](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contentScripts) / webNavigation + tabs.executeScript in FF.

Comment: You can't inject a matches parameter from user input. 
You must add all url into matches "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ], not only for google. and whenever url has changed, you must check your storage if "matches_url" is the same as the current url you visit on the background "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },, then you call your script manually.